# The law requires that there shall be no delay

Tags: word-usage

The law requires that there shall be no delay.

Q: In this sentence I think 'should' (not shall) is right. Am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Shall* is correct.

Comment: Please see also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: You can circumvent the problem by using the _mandative subjunctive_, which requires neither _shall_ nor _should_: _The law requires that there be no delay_. See https://www.thoughtco.com/mandative-subjunctive-term-1691299

Comment: Thank you for asking. When a question asks for proofreading or rewriting (“how should I write this?”, “is this correct?”, “which is correct?”), that is out of scope for this site and may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” try asking that question instead. Also check out: “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to mean the term as a mandatory line, then, a **"must"** must be used rather than "shall" or "should" (honestly, I think it's not even applicable in law if you ask me)

Nearly every jurisdiction has held that the word "shall" as confusing because it can also mean "may, will or must." As you can see, shall just cannot seem obligatory.

Here's an example that might help you

- Incoming materials ***must be*** inspected before they are accepted in
  warehouse.
- Incoming materials ***shall be*** inspected before they are accepted in    warehouse.
- Incoming materials ***should be*** inspected before they are accepted in    warehouse.

The first point makes it obvious that the material definitely should be checked.

The second point makes it seem like it's "okay" even if you don't check.

But when we come to the third point, try comparing it with the first one and you'll find it that the first point has more force rather then the third.

Hence, it's a "must" but since you've asked about "shall" or "should"; I'd vouch for the "shall" since that's more of a "legal" word.

---

*Footlinks:-*

- https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/plain_language/articles/mandatory/
- http://asq.org/standards-shall-should

Comment: See also https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt